# How to get WM_TOUCH messages in a message-only window

Tags: windows, winapi, input, touch

I've just begun a project and I want to receive all the touch events from a touch screen to process them, whichever the active window. I am using the Win32 API with C++ (I am new to Win32 programming). I'd like to use a message-only window but I don't succeed in getting WM_TOUCH message with it (though I think it is properly created and registered for touch events). Here is my function which initialises the message-only window.

```
HWND InitMessageOnlyWindow(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow) {
    LPWSTR szWindowClassName = TEXT("msgOnly");

    WNDCLASSEX windowClass;
    memset(&windowClass, 0, sizeof(windowClass));
    windowClass.cbSize = sizeof(windowClass);
    windowClass.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    windowClass.lpszClassName  = szWindowClassName;
    if(RegisterClassEx(&windowClass)==0) {
    std::cerr << "RegisterClass" << std::endl;
    return 0;
    }

    HWND hWindow = CreateWindow(
    szWindowClassName,
    L"",
    0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    HWND_MESSAGE,
    0, 0, 0);
    if (!hWindow) {
    std::cerr << "CreateWindow" << std::endl;
    return 0;
    }

    if(RegisterTouchWindow(hWindow, 0)==0) {
    std::cerr << "RegisterTouchWindow" << std::endl;
    return 0;
    }

    return hWindow;
}
```

I've tested the followings:

- to get WM_INPUT messages in the message-only window, it works.
- to get WM_TOUCH messages in a classic window, it works.

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104509/getting-input-if-the-window-is-not-active-windows) the message-only window needs to be active. I tried it, the result is odd, SetActiveWindow returns NULL (so there should be a problem) but GetLastError does not hold it. This does not make my program work. I have not dig into the hook thing yet, I'd like to know why this does not work first.

Thanks.

Comment: Erm, touch events go windows that can be active only. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371581(v=vs.85).aspx): `After the application registers its window, notifications from the Windows Touch driver are forwarded to the application when input is made on the window.` `After the first touch message is received on a window, all touch messages are sent to that window until another window receives focus.`

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Actually you can set a message-only window active (with SetActiveWindow), it receives all the expected messages so it's confusing. But indeed I have realized that Touch Input events and message-only windows are not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

use follow code ,you can register all windows which call wm_touch hook dll. function.so you can catch Wm_TOUCH messages.
RegisterTouchWindow( ((PCWPSTRUCT)lParam)->hwnd,0);